# Paperclip Remote URL

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, api, paperclip

I'm working with Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2. I am running the gem Paperclip to upload images, and this works fine.

However, I'm trying to integrate it with an API that returns just an image URL.

The plan is to run a cron job to fetch the XML output of the API, parse it, and store it in the database.

My question is, how can I use just the remote url to display the image in my application? I do not want to have to download all the images, as there are 1000s of images (only 1 per record though).

Can anyone suggest how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to display image from that remote url, can't you just store that url in the database and use it in the `image_tag`? Paperclip seems irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Sure in the latest version of paperclip (you might have to link it to the unreleased version in github). (Version > 3.1.3)

You can do something like this

```
self.your_paperclip_attachment_attribute = URI.parse("http://some.com/url/withimage.png")
```

That will download and link the attachment to your model.